# Unregistered-Type Resolution With .NET Core DI Container

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Is there any way to register a "catch all" to the .net core dependency injection? That uses any dependencies it has and makes a instance? I know this worked in old framework apps (using StructureMap) and cant find a way to do it in .net core (without using a extra NuGet package). As a very simple example trying to get `UnkownClass` throws a exception

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DICatchAllTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging()
                                                  .AddSingleton<KnownClass>();

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UnknownClass>();
        }
    }

    public class KnownClass
    {
        public KnownClass(ILogger<KnownClass> logger, UnknownClass unknownClass)
        {
            //Set these to properties to be used late
        }
    }

    public class UnknownClass
    {
        public UnknownClass(ILogger<UnknownClass> logger)
        {
            //Set these to properties to be used late
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get an exception as you are asking for a REQUIRED service that you haven't even registered. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: You could enumerate the services in the collection, check for missing dependencies, then add them... Sounds like an anti-pattern though. You should know what services you need. But `KnownClass` could provide a helper method to register itself and `UnknownClass`.

Comment: Certainly isn't an anti-pattern. There's a reason most mature DI Containers contain features for this. Very useful for integration purposes and doing last-minute registrations. Still --when possible-- prefer Auto-Registration, where all required types are iterated at startup and registered. But either way, what you are looking for is typically called *unregistered type resolution* and is not something that MS.DI supports, and it is impossible to extend MS.DI to support this. If you really need this (which is not something you explained in the question), move to a mature DI Container.

Comment: @Steven thanks for the info. I had suspected it wasn't possible without a separate container but was hoping it would work with the default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose with "catch all" you mean you'd like the DI-container to find the required types itself without you having to register them. That's indeed a feature that some DI-frameworks have but the .net one does not. However, there are many libraries that allow you to accomplish this. For example [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor). [Here](https://alimozdemir.medium.com/better-di-service-registration-with-assembly-scan-3e0329e8e30a) is an example of how to use it.

Comment: Scrutor supports Auto-Registration; I think OP is looking for Unregistered-Type Resolution, which is something different, and not something Scrutor adds on top of MS.DI.

Answer (score 1):

As @Steven explained it is not something that is supported by the out of the box .net core DI container. So I will look into a third party container for this functionality.